# First column in Excel should continuously repeated in datagrid

Tags: c#, excel, datagrid

I have an Excel file with 2 columns [file in my pc]? Now iam getting 2 columns with 8 rows with below code.but continuously i should get  5*2=10 more of same columns with 8 rows in datagridview.

I have written the code which gives result only 2 columns but I should get 10 more columns with 8 rows.below is my code

```
    for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());
    }

    for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= 9; Rnum++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString(),
                    (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: try put loop for adding columns out

Comment: is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
             {
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell txtbx = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

            DataGridViewColumn txcol = new DataGridViewColumn();

            txcol.CellTemplate = txtbx;

            txcol.HeaderText = "column" + i.ToString();

            dg1.Columns.Add(txcol);

            }
        dg1.Rows.Add(8);
        int dgRw, dgCol;
        dgRw = dgCol = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dg1[dgCol, dgRw].Value = dr[0].ToString();       

            dgRw++;
            if (dgRw == 8)
            {
                dgCol++;            
                dgRw = 0;
            }
```